# how do I resolve redis socketio error when running bench start?

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I am getting this error while trying to run bench start. I am using docker to install Frappe bench.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rXou.png)

I have checked all the config files and they have the redis socketio configured but still bench start wont run.